# How to Update/Insert a collection in Entity framework 4.1 with one to many relation

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, insert-update, one-to-many

How to Update/Insert a collection in Entity framework with one to many relation.

When I try to save blog, I wish to update/insert comments at the same time in the related table.

Am getting "Entity framework, referential integrity constraint violation occurred error on updating " when I try to Update the blog entity having a new comment added.

For example:

```cs
public class blog
{
    public int blogId {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<comments> {get;set;}
}

public class Comments
{
    public int CommentsId {get;set;}

    public int blogId {get;set;}

    this.Hasequired(t=>t.Blog)
        .WithMany(t=>t.Comments)
        .HasForiegnKey(t=>t.BlogId);
}
```

Comment: This is not an example of what you want to _do_. The question is not clear. Please add some code (by editing your question) that shows what you try to achieve.

Comment: Am getting "Entity framework, referential integrity constraint violation occurred error on updating " when I try to Update the blog entity having a new comment added.

Comment: Without the code that causes the exception no one can help you.